# Programmatically reading a Microsoft Word document

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, ms-word

I have my students submit their Microsoft Word assignments to a ColdFusion 10 server.  I'd like to write an error checker to check for common mistakes like not having a page number in the header, the name of the school on the title page, their name on the title page, etc. I specify a lot of APA rules. Example: The phrase "Running head:" must be in the header section of page 1 but not the rest of the paper.  I assign a point value to each rule.

Ideally, this error checker would run when they submit the assignment and tell them immediately.  That might require using

```
parser.parseFromString(str, "text/xml");
```

But as an alternate, if I could write a program that I run to check for errors, that could help automate my grading.  In other words, using Microsoft Access or Visual Studio.
But I don't want to do that because then I'd have to have Visual Studio on the server and I don't think that's going to be feasible.

The last option would be to download all the papers off the server and run a program locally, which is one step better than grading everything manually.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: C'mon guys.  I have 70 students...

Comment: Phillip - NO worries!  Many people, like myself, come here for assistance; however, there are some that live on judgements no matter where you go!  Ignore the hecklers.   ;)  This is why you are allowed to mark comments as Offensive/Not Constructive (just hover to the left of the comment and you will find the icon.)

Comment: Lol how is this "lazy"? I'd called it efficient

Comment: @Ian - Forget about technology and efficiency. Manual effort builds character ;-)

Comment: I seriously question the language comprehension powers of the people that closed this question, and whether they are fit to do the jobs they have appointed themselves to do. The question is very clear, which is evidenced by the fact IT HAD ALREADY BEEN ANSWERED by the time the close vote had been made. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @Phillip maybe you need to add an explicit "so how do I do the parsing of the Word doc", because - despite that's obviously implied in your question, some people seem to not be able to make that inference.

Comment: @AdamCameron I've developed a thick skin when it comes to StackOverflow.

Comment: @Phillip... well that's good. But I'd rather people didn't have to. This hair-trigger question-closing needs to be stopped.

Comment: A while back I had to attempt to read powerpoint slides with ColdFusion.  Working on this led me to the Apache POI where I was not only able to find information about reading PowerPoint, but also Word.  This approach may or may not be better than the answers already provided.

Comment: OK Dan, thanks.  I think POI might be getting in over my head.

Comment: POI is great for Excel, but the Word package is less mature. From what you have described, you are probably better off with VBA (given that is feasible in your case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this a few years back using VBA, refer to this [article](http://visualbasic.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/vb-vba-l/vba-to-read-line-by-line-from-word-document-1821519#M1822258).  Here is an excerpt that parses each paragraph of a document:

```
Public Sub ParseLines()
    Dim singleLine As Paragraph
    Dim lineText As String

    For Each singleLine In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        lineText = singleLine.Range.Text

        '// parse the text here...

    Next singleLine
End Sub
```

Comment: VBA is Visual Basic for Applications, right?  I think that's in Microsoft Access, which I do have.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  You can run VBA in Microsoft Office products, including Access.  You can also use PHP if you would like, refer to http://www.blogs.zeenor.com/it/read-ms-word-docx-ms-word-2007-file-document-using-php.html.

Comment: Also, if you are looking for someone to author something for you, there are many people out there that can do it for you via websites like Elance.com, etc.

Comment: [The docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194253.aspx) say "Use the DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter property with the PageSetup object to specify a different first page."  This is exactly what I'm looking for because "use different first page" is one of the things that a lot of students forget to set.  VBA is probably the best approach because it's treating the document as an object.

Comment: Excellent news Phillip!  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I know you already found an answer, but I thought Id throw in Apache POI to extract the data from the word document.  I know you can get the headers of the pages like so

```
fis = createObject("java","java.io.FileInputStream").init(ExpandPath('./mydoc.docx'));
document = createObject("java","org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument").init(fis);
fis.close();

policy = document.getHeaderFooterPolicy();
firstHeader = policy.getFirstPageHeader().getText();
defaultHeader = policy.getDefaultHeader().getText();
```

I know this is only the header portion of your request.  There is a way to get the even and odd page headers too looking at the documentation.

[APACHE POI](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/index.html)

Comment: Interesting.  Has potential. @abbottmv

Answer (score 1):

Try out:

http://docxextractor.riaforge.org/

I extracts all clear and some of the formatting

Disclaimer: I wrote it

Comment: Thanks James.  I always forget to first check on riaforge.  I did a cfdump of this.xmlPara and it seems a little incomplete.  For example, I need to know what font they are using.  Do you think there's any chance of getting info like that?  Like I don't see info about the headers and footers.

Comment: It has been a while since I worked on it, but I think it came down to docx does not have a clean style sheet mechanism. When making the coverter, I only focused on certain things, because docx does many many things that don't translate into HTML cleanly

Comment: I'm revisiting this issue (new semester).  It looks like Ray has a blog post at: http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/8/16/getAllTheTexts--simple-Apache-Tika-wrapper  but I'm lost as to how to install Tika, etc.