# Convery doc to html with coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, ms-word

I know coldfusion has some handling for word docs, namely converting them to .pdf. I want to show a document inline without my users having to convert them. Can I programmatically perform the "save as..." int the "wsFormatFilteredHTML" format?

Comment: ColdFusion has [no native support for converting MS Word to HTML](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/office-file-interoperability/supported-office-conversion-formats.html). You will need to find a third party tool.

Comment: Word docs are zip of xml. You can parse through the that XML and generate xml. An example is: https://github.com/jmohler1970/WordExtractor Disclaimer: I wrote this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically reading a Microsoft Word document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14655315/programmatically-reading-a-microsoft-word-document)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

If your word content is a variable:

```
<cfheader name=“Content-disposition” value=“attachment;filename=blah.docx”>
<cfcontent type="application/msword" reset="yes">
#wordconent#
```

If it's an actual file you should be able to serve directly:

```
<cfcontent type="application/msword" file="path/filename.docx">
```

That's from memory so it might take some trial and error. good luck :)